# images not displayed in heroku website despite being visible from s3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

The image from s3 has an enscription, while after opening the image from the website there is no enscription. I am not sure if this is the problem. How can i solve this or how can I get rid of the enscription?

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxxxxxxxxx"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="rrrrrrrrr"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME="ddddddddd"
SECRET_KEY="44444"


AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'mysite/media' 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information about the problem. How are you accessing the images? Show the template.

Comment: through amazon s3. the website is able to store uploads to amazon s3.also when i click view image from the website the url is the same as that in s3 same image except that there is no enscription to that in my website . is there a way that i  can get rid of the enscription ?? ? before using s3 the images were visible in the website but kept on dissapearing after about an hour . do i have to edit my template after changing static and media storage?? kindly help i know i have not explained it well

Comment: <img class="border border-grey rounded-circle"  src="{% if user.shop.image %}
                              {{ user.shop.image.url  }}{% else %}{% endif  %}
                              " class="img-responsive" alt="no image" style="width:5.5rem; height:5.5rem; " alt="Card image cap">